# Difficulty passing arguments into function?

Tags: php

I'd like to pass it's value as an argument into my function

```
function dostuff($input) {
global $input;

    if ($input == 5) {
        $output = "Success";
    } else {
        $output = "Failure";
    }
echo $output;
}
```

Why does running

```
dostuff(5);
```

Not echo the output variable ("Success") like it's supposed to?

Comment: I'm not getting it... why do you have `$input = 5;` if you use `dostuff(5)` anyways ?

Comment: I think no need of global $input;

Comment: Because you use the global variable `$input` with `global $input;` and this is not equal to 5.

Comment: And generally it's not a good idea to `echo` inside functions, you should instead `return` it and echo it in the global scope. This is to avoid unwanted prints in your code.

Comment: Although, if you just define `$input` prior to calling the function, it should work. https://3v4l.org/kBpX9 But again, using `global` in it self is a bad thing, even worse when you're already passing it as an argument to the function.

Comment: @Qirel Interesting, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to set `global $input;`, try this:

```
function dostuff($input) {
    if ($input == 5) {
        $output = "Success";
    } else {
        $output = "Failure";
    }
echo $output;
}
```

With this, `dostuff(5)` return "Success"

Explanation:

`global` is to used **global variable** into your function (http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php), you don't need it because you passed `$input` in **function parameters**.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I try to edit my post with more explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on Jouby’s explanation:

In PHP, unlike many other languages, variables are, by default, **local** variables. This simplifies some aspects of writing safe functions (with fewer accidental side-effects), but does require an extra step if you really want to use global variables.

In a function definition, parameter variables are really specialised local variables. The magic part of a parameter variable is that it is assigned automatically when yo call the function.

The `global` keyword in PHP associates the variable name to the global variable, effectively replacing the local variable. *You only need to use `global` if you want to use global data, which is not generally a good idea*.

In your example, that’s exactly what you have done. You have clobbered your local parameter with a non-existent global variable. Just remove that statement, and things should work.